# Construct a proof tree in Hindley-Milner with function overload

Tags: type-theory

I'm reading Wadler's paper called "[How to make adhoc polymorphism less ad hoc](https://people.csail.mit.edu/dnj/teaching/6898/papers/wadler88.pdf)".
I'm trying to understand the given rules for function overload (over and inst) and I want to create a small example of a proof tree using them. All deductions rules are in Figure 9 and Figure 10.

I decided to proof the following expression/type: $(over\: eq:: Eq\: \alpha\: in\: inst\: eq :: Eq\:Int \:=\: eqInt\: in\: eq\:1\:2)::Bool$.

Some people gave me a tip: construct the tree in bottom-up.

So here is what I did:
[image: Tree proof]

I think I'm stuck. I have no idea how to go up in the tree. And I'm not sure if I can, at some point, discharge the assumption about $eqInt$.

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong and how to finish this proof.

---

EDIT:
As said in the paper, $Eq\: \tau$ is a abbreviation for $\tau \rightarrow \tau \rightarrow Bool$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I realized that is not possible to proof 
\begin{align*}
\vdash (over\: eq:: Eq\: \alpha\: in\: inst\: eq :: Eq\:Int \:=\: eqInt\: in\: eq\:1\:2)::Bool
\end{align*}
 without suppositions about $1$, $2$ and $eqInt$ ( $\emptyset$ as the context). They need to be bound to the context , because they should be seen as build in
to the system. In alternative I could create new rules (like $const$ rules) for the integer numbers ($1$, $2$...) and for $eqInt$, that don't insert stuff to the context.

So, my final result is this proof tree:
[image]

I'm not sure if I can use $weakening$ in the context, but I did.

I hope that some one could comment something about my answer. If I'm right or if I created some non-sense.